# django query foreign relationship

Tags: python, django

I want to ask is I want to filter `AAMovieShowtime` where it's title in `AAMovie` is 'ABC'
What can I do?

I try this but not work:

```
obj2 = AAMovieShowtime.objects.filter( movie__title='ABC' )
```

Here is my model:

```
class AAMovie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

class AAMovieShowtime(models.Model):
    movie = models.ForeignKey( AAMovie, null=True,blank=True,related_name = 'movie' )
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not work"?  The code seems fine.

Comment: ？ but my obj2 got nothing

Comment: You can try the contains filter may be your title field carries extra characters..!!

Comment: If `obj2` is empty then you don't have `AAMovieShowtime` with `movie.title=='ABC'`.  Create such objects and try again.

Comment: I believe there is no data available. To test, just do `AAMovieShowtime.objects.filter(movie__title='ABC').count()` Or even just `AAMovieShowtime.objects.count()` just to verify it indeed exists. Note that by default, it is an exact match, case sensitive search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
movies = AAMovie.objects.filter(title='ABC')
```

If `movies` is empty then you don't have movies titled 'ABC'.  If `movies` is not empty then try this:

```
showtimes = AAMovieShowtime.filter(movie__in=movies)
```

If `showtimes` is empty then you don't have objects related to these movies.

Just in case if you want case insensitive search by part of the title then try:

```
showtimes = AAMovieShowtime.objects.filter(movie__title__icontains='ABC' )
```